# How to validate the radio button inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the below code for student's assignment status marking. My problem is it is not necessary that all students should be marked. The user might mark some might not. Now  how to validate that at least one user must be marked else there should be some validation message displayed.

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Complete</th>
                        <th>Incomplete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="record in studentRecord.AssignmentStatus">
                        <td>{{record.Name}}</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value=Complete ng-model="record.Status" /></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value=Incomplete ng-model="record.Status" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="updateAssignment(studentRecord)">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the doc

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

try it

```
<form name="myForm">
<td><input type="radio" value="Complete" ng-model="record.Status" ng-required="true" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="Incomplete" ng-model="record.Status" ng-required="true" /></td>
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This seems nice option to be followed but I don't have to put submit button for each as per the requirement and second is form inside table is bad programming for whom I made this. Still full marks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

ThomasP1988 pretty much has it there, but here is a fiddle with an example.

```
<input type="radio" value="Incomplete" ng-model="record.Status" ng-required="true" />
```

The key here is that by using 'ng-required' you can get a value back from 'formName.$invalid', which will determine whether it passed the built in angular validation directives.

http://jsfiddle.net/glandrum101/9gWR9/1/

Here is the documentation for forms in AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

If you go to the 'Custom Validation' section you can see some other AngularJS validation directives that can be used on form elements.

Comment: This advice seems good but has a problem. We can not put ng-required in the case of radio button inside ng-repeat. As you can see in your fiddle, It is asking for both radio button to be selected which is not possible. That trick is generally not good in the case where we want either thing to be selected inside ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Complete</th>
                        <th>Incomplete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="record in studentRecord.AssignmentStatus">
                        <td>{{record.Name}}</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value=Complete ng-change="change()" ng-model="record.Status" /></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value=Incomplete ng-change="change()" ng-model="record.Status" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="changeOfValue==0" ng-click="updateAssignment(studentRecord)">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

This is what I have done to check if any of the radio button has ever been pushed or used then in that case I will let the user proceed with submission.

```
PageController.prototype.change = function () {
        this.$scope.changeOfValue = 1;
    };
```

and this makes my button enable or disable.

Thanks @ThomasP1988 and @glandrum1010 for your help. I have learnt more about form element in angular but that thing is not for this problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

> This advice seems good but has a problem. We can not put ng-required in the case of radio button inside ng-repeat. As you can see in your fiddle, It is asking for both radio button to be selected which is not possible. That trick is generally not good in the case where we want either thing to be selected inside ng-repeat. –

*I disagree with glandrum101 (the author of the statements above).
Well while that might be true, you can add some code in the controller to make this work.*

#### controller:

```
Just put this code in the controller and use it with ng-change:

vm.setTrueFalseRadioState = setTrueFalseRadioState;

function setTrueFalseRadioState(answer) {
  angular.forEach(vm.AssignmentStatus, function(a) {
    if (a.Status !== answer.Status) {
      a.Status = false;
    }
  });
}
```

#### html:

```
<input type="radio" id="myChoice_{{$index + 1}}" name="response" ng-required="!record.Status" ng-change="studentRecord.setTrueFalseRadioState(record)" value="true" ng-model="record.Status" />
```

[I made a sample plunker to demonstrate this](http://plnkr.co/edit/6VD58MNJfRaHdeAukHas?p=preview)